# Angular Firebase User Email Verification to a different email

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular7

I have a website that only accepts email from a specific domain, this case a university domain. If the user wants to sign up using facebook or google, they need to verify that they have an email from the university but I don't find a way to send the verification email to the university email.

I have tried

```
SendVerificationEmailSocialMedial(email) {
    return this.afsAuth.auth.currentUser.sendEmailVerification(email)
    .catch((error) => {
      window.alert(error)
    })
  }
```

---

```
SendVerificationEmailSocialMedial(email) {
    return this.afsAuth.auth.email.sendEmailVerification()
    .catch((error) => {
      window.alert(error)
    })
  }
```

---

This the only thing that have worked

```
SendVerificationEmailSocialMedial(email){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.afsAuth.auth.currentUser.updateEmail(email)
        .then(userData => {
          this.SendVerificationMail();
        }).catch(err => console.log(reject(err)))
    });
  }
```

I changed the email of the user but I don't want to change it, just to verify the email because the user receives an email with the changes

A solution, but I don't know if is possible, I would change the email of the user, send the verification and change it back to the original user email, if that works that is amazing, but Im not sure if that would work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is not possible, because a user might use his/her facebook, which is supposedly not registered under the uni email. Thereon, user signs in to the firebase-auth system using this 3rd party email. As firebase will only recognize this as a official email without any changes, you can only send email to this specific email address.

However what you can do is, put an additional registration flow page where you ask their email and tell them that this should be replaced in order to register to the system for full access..

Comment: Change the main email ? 

It is possible to change the email of a user without sending an email ?

Comment: I found a solution using firestore, instead of using emailVerified and admin SDK. 

When the user loggin, the app will check if is social media or email, and depending on that it will use a firebase unique variable like emailVerified or the user emailVerified variable user document from the database Cloud Store, which is false when the user creates the account or null if is not using social media